# Get raw value from custom string type

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type AssetID string

func main() {
    p := AssetID("photo")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", p)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", p)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", p)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p)
    fmt.Println(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprintf("%#v", p), `"`))
}

func (aid AssetID) String() string {
    switch aid {
    case "photo":
        return "Photos!"
    default:
        return "Unknown asset ID"
    }
}
```

(source: https://play.golang.org/p/YU70wWtws4N)

I'm using these AssetIDs in my `html/template` setup. But the problem occurs when I want to turn  `[]AssetID` into a HTML `<select>` statement.

What I want:

```
<select>
<option value="photo">Photos!</option>
</select>
```

What I get (without the special printf stuff in the example above.):

```
<select>
<option value="Photos!">Photos!</option>
</select>
```

Is there another way to fix this?

Edit: some more info;
I'd like to have both and I wanted to ideally keep the Stringer functionality working so I could use `//go generate stringer`.
I'm okay with the answer being; this is not really possible.

Comment: Alright, apparently the point is moot as Stringer doesn't handle non-integer keys such as strings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're (apparently inadvertently) implementing the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface, which `fmt.Sprintf` uses to format the value.

By adding a function with the signature `String() string` to you're type, you're telling `fmt.Sprintf` to call that function to format it.

The simplest way to solve your problem would be to rename your function to something else.  Perhaps:

```golang
func (aid AssetID) Description() string {
    switch aid {
    case "photo":
        return "Photos!"
    default:
        return "Unknown asset ID"
    }
}
```